# Is it sleeping or hibernating?

Tags: laptop, sleep, hibernate

Simple question, when I close the lid on my laptop, is it suspending to RAM or to disk?
If it depends on the laptop, than how can I find out?

EDIT:Running Windows vista and 7 RTM on dual boot.

Comment: Pull the battery out after you close the lid :-)  Little destructive...but you'll definitely know ;-)

Comment: What operating system you're running would probably have been a useful piece of data.

Comment: Woops, sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hibernation is when the contents of the RAM is saved to disk and the device is then turned off. So if the power LED is blinking or changed color, the laptop is in sleep mode. If it's off, then it has hibernated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not on a laptop at the moment so I can't really check this. In the power options in Vista and Windows 7 ( don't know about XP ) you have settings for "when I close the lid" there you can specify if it should sleep or hibernate.

[Here's a guide from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-NZ/windows-vista/Change-what-happens-when-you-close-your-mobile-PC-lid)

Comment: I'm not on a laptop raight now either, but I'm sure gonna check it out.

Answer (score 0):

XP has it available too. In Power Options under the Advanced tabs you can specify what to do when the lid is closed. The options are Stand By, Hibernate, Do Nothing.

I usually use Stand By or Sleep since it's saved to ram. It's quicker to start back up. If you leave your laptop long enough to drain the battery you would want to Hibernate.

To answer your question, it depends on how it's setup in Power Options/Management.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell by the time it takes for your laptop to wake up again.
If it takes a second or two, then it was just sleeping.
If it takes ten seconds or more, then it was hibernated.

Comment: It will also go through a boot sequence if hibernated rather than open the display directly to the OS screen.